# Crontab job scheduling is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, scheduling

I have script which pull some data from remote database and write to a text file.
This text file used to populate the local database.

If I run the individual script it is working as expected(Update the text file with records).

Its not working if added this script in crontab.

Crontab Expression:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/todb >>/usr/bin/mycommand.log
```

Observations:the text file time stamp will change for the scheduled time but it is not getting updated with records.(O bytes) and it applies same for mycommand.log file also.

Bash Script:

```
file="/usr/bin/todb.txt"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
rm /usr/bin/todb.txt 
fi
engineers_list=( abc 123 hjk )
for i in "${engineers_list[@]}"
do
    fing -s JKL  "( ( [Duplicate-on] >= 06/01/2014  ) and  [Engineer] = '$i' )" -w Identifier,DE-manager,Engineer -D ^ >> /usr/bin/todb.txt
done
```

Comment: Can you show us the script that is being executed. It could be a relative/absolute path issue within the script itself

Comment: Are you sure that cron deamon is running? Try to run `pgrep cron` and make sure that there's number associated.

Comment: Please show `/usr/bin/todb` script. Are Your script use some ENV vars?

Comment: yes everything is fine and even in syslog i can see the entry of this script except it is not updated the text.   In script im using absolute path to create text file like(/usr/bin/abc.txt).

Comment: Hi vitozev ,yes deamon is running.Even i am not using any ENV variables

Comment: The script has no output, as far as i can tell, thus `mycommand.log` will be empty. The `todb.txt` file could be empty (if it is) because your query simply does not match anything (hard to tell how the `fing` command behaves) - besides why not use `$file` throughout the script?

Comment: Aside from that: `/usr/bin` is supposed to hold executable files only. Depending on the situation, data files should either go beyond `$HOME`, `[/var]/tmp` or – most fitting for your case – `/var/log`. Please see the [article on FHS (or **F**ile **H**ierarchy ***S***tandard) for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). BTW: the ability to write to `/usr/bin` implies that the cronjob is run as the `root` user, which you really should not do unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes the reason I placed in /usr/bin because of administrative purpose.Even I am running as root user only .@Christian.K fing will give some tuples that I am redirecting to a todb.txt file .The mycommand.log to check if the job ran successfully or not.

Comment: @Tomasz Yeah I am redirecting output of fing command to a file todb.txt.This is getting updated with records if i run by going to absolute path .But , through cronjob the time stamp only get changes but not with the records.I am least bothered about mycommand.log ,I added this bcz wanted to know the command has successfully executed or not.

Comment: What fing command do?

Comment: fing will give numerous fields with space as the delimiter.Fing will give output and its redirected to file as well without crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Output is in `/usr/bin/todb.txt` file, not in `/usr/bin/mycommand.log`.

`/usr/bin/mycommand.log` is touched (and timestamp is changed) bt all output is redirected to `/usr/bin/mycommand.log`.

Command

```
/usr/bin/todb >> /usr/bin/mycommand.log
```

redirects only `stdout` to `mycommand.log`. To redirect `stdout` and `stderr` try:

```
/usr/bin/todb >> /usr/bin/mycommand.log 2>&1
```

I guess Your script not find `fing` command.

Comment: you are correct output will be directed to todb.txt.The reason I added mycommand.log to check the command is executed or because of something got failed.I am least concerned about mycommand.log file.My issue with todb.txt file only.Independently if i execute the above script it runs successfully without any failures.But , with the crontab only its not getting filled with database information.

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership of the `todb.txt` file, and under which user profile are you scheduling the crontab?

Comment: rw-r--r--...Even if i change the permission to 777 it automatically changes to rw-r--r--.Any way through the root user  only im running the script .It has write permission.Scheduling under the root user.